# OpenGL + Cocoa and a proper rendering context

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, opengl, opengl-3

I'm trying to set up a basic OpenGL-based app that renders a simple triangle, using the OpenGL3 Core Profile.

However, whenever I try to make any OpenGL calls to actually render a frame I get 
`GL_INVALID_FRAMEBUFFER_OPERATION` when trying to create a VAO or `GL_INVALID_OPERATION` when actually making any rendering calls.

These are the pixel format attributes I'm using to create the context:

```
NSOpenGLPixelFormatAttribute attribs[] = {
            NSOpenGLPFAColorSize, 32,
            NSOpenGLPFADoubleBuffer,
            NSOpenGLPFASingleRenderer,
            NSOpenGLPFAOpenGLProfile,
            NSOpenGLProfileVersion3_2Core,
            0 
};
```

As well as checking for the status of the framebuffer before actually doing anything by using `glCheckFramebufferStatus` (which returns `GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE`, yet the earlier errors persist).

What am I doing wrong? In case I'm not supplying enough information about my experiment (rather new to OpenGL) please tell me in the comments.

Comment: Well, creating a GL rendering window by hand is quite tedious, plus you would have to fetch function pointers for the core context functions. Why don't you use some helper library such as GLFW and GLEW?

http://www.glfw.org/
http://glew.sourceforge.net/

Comment: BTW, just encountered this other question that might be of help:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22427776/the-simplest-minimalistic-opengl-3-2-cocoa-project?rq=1

Comment: @glampert Well I guess I found the problem, but the alternate pixelFormat in the link you sent me was helpful, so thanks for that.